# Android: Laying 2 Webviews side by side

Tags: android, webview

I have a LinearLayout followed by a Button, then 2 webviews and then another LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout. The webviews need to be side by side. You can imagine it looking like http://developer.android.com/training/ left hand menu and right hand content, top menu and bottom footer.

When the button is clicked, the webviews are loaded. However, this is not working. Only one webview is loading content. I notice if I remove "layout_toRightOf" from the webview and display the webview below one another, then it works fine. Alternatively, if I remove "layout_toRightOf" and use "layout_toLeftOf" for the other webview. then the laer webview display content. Please advise, how I could achieve this.

I have also tried Table Layout but no luck. I have tried wrap_content or fixed width but no luck either.

Also, please advise how I can show hide the left webview by clicking an icon or something. When this happens, the right webview should stretch to full width. I have included my code for reference.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/menu_height"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llayoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="some text on top edit" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button top" />
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_bGetFile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/llayoutTop"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="getFiles"
    android:text="@string/button_getFiles" />    

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/home_webViewLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/home_bGetFile" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/home_webViewRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/home_bGetFile"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/home_webViewLeft" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llayoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="some text on bottom edit" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to show your `webView` side by side the best thing is to put them into a `LinearLayout` and set their respective weight to 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/menu_height"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="some text on top edit" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button top" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home_bGetFile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/llayoutTop"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="getFiles"
        android:text="@string/button_getFiles" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llayoutBottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/home_bGetFile" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/home_webViewLeft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/home_webViewRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="some text on bottom edit" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `WebViews` in a `LinearLayout`, then set their `width` to 0, and their `weight` to 1.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/home_bGetFile">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/home_webViewLeft"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/home_webViewRight"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The reason what you're doing doesn't work, is because the first `WebView` is setting it's width to `"wrap_content"`, which is likely causing it to take up the whole screen, then you're trying to tell the other view to sit to the right of that (off the screen). `RelativeLayouts` are just that - their positions are relative to each other. So unless you set the width to exactly half the width of the screen (difficult to do), you're better of using a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Well, the whole idea is to minimise the number of layouts, so I would prefer not using the LinearLayouts if the there is any other way. Regarding, WebView taking whole width, I have set a smaller width value as well but no luck. Whichever WebView has "layout_toRightOf" or "layout_toLeftOf" does not appear.

Comment: Hard to say without testing it myself, which I can't do right now, but if you set the left `WebView` width to say, 100dp and the right width to `match_parent`, then lay the right `WebView` `toRightOf` the left `WebView`, it _should_ display. Maybe the one whose width you specified as `wrap_content` had no content at layout time, so it set it's width to 0? In any case, the simplest most effective way to achieve your desired result is to include the additional `LinearLayout`.

Comment: user2341601 this is the answer to your question.